# Creating an html form within php while loop

Tags: php

I am new to php. I have created a clients database in mysql and now i wish to edit it via a web browser, hence am creating a very basic web app.

I wish to view the clients list in the form of text fields with an edit button next to them. I am trying to create an html form within php but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me out. Code is per below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Price List</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {text-align: center;}
        h1 {font-family: "Times New Roman";}
        h1 {color: #060;}
        p {text-align: justify;}
        p {font-family: "Times New Roman";}
        p {font-size: 16px;}
        table {border-color: #060}


    table {border-style: double;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body background="background/lgrey_background.gif">
    <center>
    <table border="2" width="750">
        <tr>




    <td colspan="2">




    <img src = "upper_banner/upper_banner.jpg" alt ="Upper Banner"/>
            </td>


        </tr>
        <tr>


    <td colspan="2">

            </td>    
        </tr>




    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <h1>Clients List</h1>
        <p>
        The following is the clients list:
        </p>
        <center>
        <table border="1">

    <tr>
        <td><strong>ID</strong></td><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td><strong>Surname</strong></td>
        </tr>
   <?php            
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","admin", "XXX", "clients db");
        if ($connect->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
        } 

        $query = "SELECT id, name, surname FROM clients";
        $executequery = $connect->query($query);
        if ($executequery->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $executequery->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo'
                    <form method="post" action="update_clients_list.php">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="id" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[id]"?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[name]"?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="surname" size="20" value="<?php echo "$row[surname]"?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit value" value="Edit">
                    </td>
                </tr>';

        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        ?>

    </table>
    </center>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>

        <a href="site_map.php">Site Map</a>

    </td>
        <td>
        </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `enter code here`

Comment: how did you manage to get all this "enter code here" in here??

Comment: please re-post your code without them.

Comment: this `value="<?php echo "$row[id]"?>">` should be without the `"` around the variable name but with`'` inside: `value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">`

Comment: oops, and you can't do `<?php` inside an echo statement! Looks like coopy&paste code, right?

Comment: first I did put some code in a normal table and worked fine to view some data but then I did cut it and paste it in the form

Answer (score 0):

```
Since you are new on PHP I would suggest you to review the usage of templates, like smarty or Blade, You will find how easy would result to achieve this type of projects.

For this specific project you will need to create a grid (table) then in front of each row add a simple form with a hidden values that will let you edit each client

Something like this

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Carter</td>
            <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
            <td>
                 <form method="post" action="edit-client.php" >
                 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="clientId" /> 
                 <button type="submit" value="Edit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>Parker</td>
            <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
            <td>
                 <form method="post" action="edit-client.php" >
                 <input type="hidden" value="2" name="clientId" /> 
                 <button type="submit" value="Edit" />
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Rambo</td>
            <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
            <td>
                 <form method="post" action="edit-client.php" >
                 <input type="hidden" value="3" name="clientId" /> 
                 <button type="submit" value="Edit" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. will the edit-client.php take me to another page though? I wish to remain on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

if i were you i would first put the $row[] values into variables, then in the input add them like this.

```
<input type="text" value="' . $variable . '">
```

Comment: how can i create a variable for every column?

Comment: just inside the while loop add $variable = $row['name'];

Comment: and do that for every variable, every time the while loop runs it will set a new value into that variable

Comment: and i  would put the form around the while loop